# ID light fixture manufacturer?

Tags: light-fixture, light

Does anyone know the name of the manufacturer of this fixture? Circa 2000-2006 maybe? Need to see if parts are still available.[image]

Comment: Take it down and look inside .... ?

Comment: Sadly that is the answer. They don’t put logos and models on the visible parts because that would interrupt the aesthetic. If it’s a responsible maker (and not just the cheap Cheese junkstream) it’ll be well-marked on non-visible surfaces.

Comment: Must be junk then because I've had it completely disassembled and there are no markings, tags, etc.